# how to swipe up and down a view?

Tags: android, swipe, slide, sliding

I used [this link](https://github.com/mancj/SlideUp-Android) to create a view to swipe up and down views! but there is one problem! after I slide up the view and I want to slide down to close it, I have to slide the parent view!! and the view itself can't detect the sliding!
I've tried adding this code to my mainActivity :

```
        sliderView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float touchedArea = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mViewHeight = sliderView.getHeight();
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    mViewStartPositionY = sliderView.getTranslationY();
                    mCanSlide |= sliderView.getBottom() - sliderView.getHeight() <= touchedArea;

                    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float difference = event.getRawY() - y1;
                    y2 = event.getRawY();
                    float moveTo = mViewStartPositionY + difference;
                    if(moveTo > 0 && mCanSlide) {
                        sliderView.setTranslationY(moveTo);
                    }
                    }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

but when I slide down, it has some bugs and the sliderView freeze sometimes!
how can I fixed this issue?!

or if there are any tutorials or other useful libraries, please let me know!

also, I used [this library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), but It has some issues too!

Comment: use `bottomSheetDialog` of Android.

Comment: What's goings on in logcat when it freezes?

Comment: @Amirhosein by freezing, I mean it's not going down smoothly and when I stop sliding, it freeze! I think the right way is when we slide down to somewhere, it automatically slide down the whole view! like google music app.

Comment: @AzinNilchi . I have used this buggy library and it has some issues and bugs although some of them has fixed.

Comment: @VirRajpurohit thank you for your comment! I'm reading bottomSheetDialog now and I hope it can be customized as I want!